# What is the most elegant way of partly copying object arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays of objects. `arrayOne` contain items type of `myObject1`:

```
var myObject1 = {
  Id: 1, //key
  params: { weight: 52, price: 100 },
  name: "",
  role: ""
};
```

`arrayTwo` contained items type of `myObject2`:

```
var myObject2 = {
      Id: 1, //key
      name: "real name",
      role: "real role"
    };
```

I want to copy all `names` and `roles` from `arrayTwo` to `arrayOne`.
`id` is the key, both arrays contains `myObjects` with that is mached by 'id`.

Comment: what are `array one` and `array two`?

Comment: Do you mean copy name and role from arrayTwo to arrayOne when the id's match.

Comment: The default implementation can lead to O(arrayOne.length * arrayTwo.length)

Comment: We can adjust this to a O(arrayOne.length) by using the id for indexing.
Is there any restiriction on the way you store the data?

Comment: @DubemEnyekwe after that operation I have to produce the json from the final array. Not quite sure what you mean by restrictions. and yes it should be exactly O(arrayOne.length)

Comment: Ok, give me a little bit, I'll provide something for you.

Comment: Are the two arrays congruent? ie. do their elements correspond index-by-index with each other?

Comment: @sreginogemoh check out the solution I've got. I beleive this should help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that runs in linear time.

```js
var arrayOne;  // Array containing objects of type myObject1
var arrayTwo;  // Array containing objects of type myObject2
var tempObj = {};

// Transform arrayOne to help achieve a better performing code
arrayOne.forEach(function(obj){
 tempObj[obj.id] = obj;
});

// Runs on linear time O(arrayTwo.length)
arrayTwo.forEach(function(obj){
 // Note, since I'm not adding any thing to the arrayTwo
 // I can modify it in this scope
 var match = tempObj[obj.id];
 
 if(match){
  // If a match is found
  obj.name = match.name;
  obj.role = match.role;
 }
});
```

Comment: getting error on  `tempObj[obj.id] = obj;` -> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '4' of undefined`

Comment: you missed to initialize `tempObj` => `var tempObj = [];`

Comment: Are you sure this does what the question asks, "to copy all names and roles from arrayTwo to arrayOne"?

Comment: @Roamer-1888, I'm quite curious about why you think this doesn't answer the question. Please feel free to point out any dead ends you see.

Comment: @Romaer-1888 I see your point I forgot to mention that I swap `arrayOne` and `arrayTwo` otherwhise it is copying the way around.

Comment: @sreginogemoh, that's not all. You also need to index into arrayOne. `arrayWhatever.name = something` sets a property of the array itself, without affecting any of its elements. [Here's a hybrid of That Guy's answer and mine](http://jsfiddle.net/u49a1967/2/) that actually works - my `$.extend()` in his safety shell.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 mmm...it is working for me here i created my improved version for u with a test case https://jsfiddle.net/g1m6anj3/

Comment: Apologies to all, for some reason the latest edit did not show up here until I restarted my computer a few moments ago. Yup, it's still rather longwided but will work with the corrections made at that edit.

Answer (score 2):

If the two arrays are guaranteed to be congruent, then with the use of `jQuery.extend()`, the code is trivial :

```
$.each(arrayOne, function(i, obj) {
    $.extend(obj, arrayTwo[i]);
});
```

Comment: It'll be an appropriate solution as long as the the 2 arrays will keep beeing congruent, otherwise, a different approach will be needed here.